# Unbind from unknown Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, mobile-devices, device

Please let me preface, I have no experience with Active Directory.

I am attempting to unbind my Mac devices from and I’m not 100% clear if their both bound to directory services through Mac as well as LDAP server or both. It appears both, and I’m unable to  find the domain name and the password?

Kerberos SSO appears to be providing access to my machines? Does that make sense to anyone? Apple is of no help and these Kerberos tokens and the domain are persistent after erase and reinstall as well as the shared Apple keychain and developer user accounts?

To make matters worse there’s mobile management profiles and Apple class room access. I was hoping unbinding would be the solution but again I’m lost in a world I haven’t a clue.

I appreciate the help and if there’s someone for hire to resolve these issues im all ears.